# Proof of identity involving binomial coefficients

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I'll be happy if you could help me prove this argument with algebraic tools:

$${N\choose 0}a^N+{N\choose 1}a^{N-2}+{N\choose 2}a^{N-4}+{N\choose 3}a^{N-6}+\dots = \frac{a^2+1}{a}$$

Thanks, Don

Comment: oops, editing is out of sync. Sorry @Zev

Comment: Very out of sync, I hope I didn't break too much editing. $\LaTeX>>$ image.

Comment: Yeah, it's looking good now, sorry about the mixup. (Didn't there use to be notifications when an edit was made to a post you were editing?)

Comment: This question has gone through 6 edits within 8 minutes. Perhaps we should let the post settle down a bit :)

Comment: I don't think the formula is correct.  I get $(a+1/a)^n$ for the binomial sum.

Comment: That's really an equality, rather than an "argument".

Answer (score 10):

The summation terminates at $\binom{N}{N}$, because once you get to $\binom{N}{k}$ with $k\gt N$, the binomial coefficient is zero. So the left hand side is equal to
$$\begin{align*}
\binom{N}{0}a^N &+ \binom{N}{1}a^{N-2} + \cdots + \binom{N}{N}a^{N-2N}\\
&\qquad= \binom{N}{0}a^N\left(\frac{1}{a}\right)^0 + \binom{N}{1}a^{N-1}\left(\frac{1}{a}\right)^1 + \cdots + \binom{N}{N}a^0\left(\frac{1}{a}\right)^N.\end{align*}$$
This is equal to 
$$\left(a+\frac{1}{a}\right)^N = \left(\frac{a^2+1}{a}\right)^N$$
by the Binomial Theorem.

So you are missing an exponent $N$ on the right.